# How can I find the speed of a falling object?

Tags: linear-algebra

Say, an observer sees an object falling at 3m/s, but there is another observer falling at 1 m/s. In the perspective of the falling observer, how fast is the object falling?

Comment: This is a Physics question. It would be better if you asked this on the Physics Stackexchange

Answer (score 0):

The object would be falling at 2 m/s with respect to the falling observer. In this situation, we can treat the first observer as stationary, so the second person is falling at 1 m/s with respect to him. Then the object is falling at a rate of 3 m/s - 1 m/s with respect to the second person.

If you are having difficulty with these types of problems, I would recommend reading up on [Newton's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion) (specifically the first law) and [Inertial Reference Frames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertial_frame_of_reference).

Lastly, this is technically a physics question, so posting it on the physics stack exchange is better.